# Question about a sequence in complex analysis :$\frac{(-1)^n n}{4n+i}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been struggling to understand how to find if this sequence diverges or converges.
How can you tell if a sequence is divergent or convergent in the complex plane, if it's not a geometric series.
This is an example of such sequence
$$\frac{(-1)^n n}{4n+i}$$

Comment: Even terms tend to $\frac 1 4$ and odd trems tend to $-\frac 1 4$.

Comment: @geetha290krm so I just do the limit as n tend to infinity

Comment: @randomdude no. Evaluating the limit "at infinity" only makes sense if the subsequence of even-indexed terms converges to the same number as the subsequence of odd-indexed terms. This one oscillates between $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$; it does not converge to a single number

Comment: Are you comfortable with understanding the limit of the similar sequence $\dfrac{(-1)^nn}{4n+1}$ which avoids complex numbers?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, i've had calculus classes before this course.

Comment: Great! The two problems are quite similar; can you use the techniques you'd use for the real-valued sequence to understand the original complex sequence?